# How to know the number of arguments of a Scilab function

Tags: scilab

Is it possible to determine the number of arguments of a function in Scilab ?

let's say I have a function as follows :

```
function T = test(t,x)
    T = t*x
endfunction
```

In this case I should get 2 as output.
To be more specific, my goal here is to know the number of arguments but uniquely using the function's name.

```
 function N = NumberArgument(F)
    // F is a function
    N = ....
 endfunction
```

And so I want to have

```
 a = NumberArgument(test)
 a = 2
```

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short:**

I think it's not possible.

**Long:**

You want to get the [*type* signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) of a function.

After a little bit of research I find out that user defined functions and some built-in function (the ones coded in scilab) have the same type:

```
-->deff('[r] = test(a, b)', 'r=a*b');
-->type(test)
 ans  =
     13.  
-->type(plot)
 ans  =
     13.
```

I think you can't have more information about a function than is type.

Now, let say you want the signature of plot.

And as you can see [here](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/plot.html) there are multiple signature (note that `plot()` without arguments is not documented).

Almost all scilab function use [argn](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/argn.html) and the signature possibility with this is illimited...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using [`argn`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/argn.html) you can determine the number of input & output arguments

```
function T = test(t,x)
    [lhs,rhs]=argn(0);
    disp(rhs);
    T = t*x;
endfunction
```

Using [`macrovar`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/macrovar.html) you can determine  the number of arguments from outside the function

```
function N = NumberArgument(F)
    // F is a function
    all_vars = macrovar(F);
    in_vars = all_vars(1);
    N = size(in_vars, 1);
endfunction

disp(NumberArgument(test))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
However, to use argn, I must call the function with actual arguments : eg test(1,2).
My goal here is to know the number of arguments but uniquely using the function's name.

     function N = NumberArgument(F)
     // F is a function
     N = ....
     endfunction
And so I want to have 

     a = NumberArgument(test)
     a = 2

Comment: Did this answer help you?